# How can I export data from DataCamp?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I use [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com) for online learning of R. Sometimes I would like to export the data used in the exercises, but I can't find an easy way to do so.

I know that there are [instructions for downloading the videos or slides](https://support.datacamp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001995913-Can-I-download-courses-for-offline-use-), and some courses provide some selected datasets for download in the course description. But how do I download data that I can access through the DataCamp exercise interface for export outside of the platform?

Comment: dput() would be one way.

Comment: @snoram, I like dput much better than my write.csv solution, since it retains the full object structure. It works fine on DataCamp. Could you please turn this comment into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comfortable way to move data from one session to another is the function `dput()`. If the data is big you could do it in steps:

```
dput(df[1:100, ])
dput(df[101:200, ])
# ...
# Finally rbind() in your local session and save to hardrive
```

Comment: This works great with DataCamp. I like dput since it retains the full object structure. dget() is the parallel function for getting the data back into R after saving to a file.

Comment: The full steps are: tmpfl <- tempfile(); dput([structure copied from DataCamp dput], tempfl); newvar <- dget(tmpfl)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually succeeded by using the DataCamp console to write the desired dataset as a CSV file, something like this in the console:

```
write.csv(df)
```

It wrote the entire output to the console and I dragged and copied the whole thing (in my case, over 4 MB of text). It was a properly formed CSV file which I saved and then imported into RStudio and then could play with as I pleased.