# How can I export data from DataCamp by using python?

Tags: python, export

I use DataCamp for the online learning of Python. Sometimes I would like to export the data used in the exercises, but I can't find an easy way to do so.

I know that there are instructions for downloading the videos or slides, and some courses provide some selected datasets for download in the course description. But how do I download data that I can access through the DataCamp exercise interface for export outside of the platform? Sometimes, the data used in the tutorial is processed and unmatched with the original data I download on the course page. Oftentimes, I need to do reverse engineering to make the local data as same as the data in the course interface before running my code and trying different things in my local environment, and it takes me a lot of time.

I tried `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`, but I couldn't find the exported data if there was one.

I saw some can [do this when learning R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523721/how-can-i-export-data-from-datacamp) Is there the same thing we can do in Python courses?

Comment: Can you Download the data to your computer? And you whant to make a dataframe of the csv file?

Comment: I can download the original dataset which is often quite different from the data used in the tutorial. The data used in the tutorial often has been cleaned and manipulated.

Comment: Do you Whant the data from tutorial, and you cant download it? The. You have to scrape it.

Comment: Can we directly write some code in the interface to export data to my local environment? It seems someone did it, learning the R on datacamp.

Comment: Can you use standard python?, you should be able to do that. Hos does the data looks like? Hos does it upload? Are u able to use the csv module?

Answer (score 0):

`write.csv` or `dput` in R write the dataframe to the console (and then you need to copy / paste the text to turn it into a csv.

If you want to do something similar you could try

`no_rows = len(df) # number of rows of dataframe`

`pd.options.display.max_rows = no_rows`

Depending on the no. of rows this can take a while and the copy/paste activity is quite cumbersome. A better approach might be to just extract a few rows so you understand the structure of the dataframe that's been processed in order to run the code with your own datasets (simulated or different ones).

Answer (score 0):

`df.to_csv()` gives you a string you can copy into your local editor. Then look for `\\n` and replace all with `\n`. Save your file as csv.

Answer (score 0):

For large data sets, the `df.to_csv()` string is too long. This is what I was able to do:

1. In the DataCamp ipython browser window, right-click on the results from `df.to_csv()` and choose "Inspect" (Chrome)
2. Click the grey arrow to display the dataframe
3. Right click on the dataframe and choose "copy element"
4. Edit the element in a text editor, or use a Python script, to replace the following:

- Replace `"\\n[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9],"` with `"\n"`
- Replace `"',"` with `""`
- Replace `"\\n'"` with `"\n"`

5. In your browser (Chrome) press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to get out of debug mode.

Comment: So you know: there's a ban on ChatGPT-generated answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Answer (score 0):

#DataFrame "df" which is already loaded in DataCamp to csv

```
df.to_csv("xyz.csv")
```

#Display the contents of the now loaded csv in IPython shell

```
!cat xyz.csv
```

#Copy and Paste it to text file in your local machine and then convert to csv